# Joining two lists of dicts based on unique key in Jinja2/Ansible using map() function

Tags: templates, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I'll state the end goal in case some has a better idea. I am trying to set up host monitoring in nagios using ansible. I want to use collections of variables to define defaults for some services and have those variables be able to be overwritten by more specific variables.

So I end up with two lists of dicts and would like to have the first list be the defaults and merge it with a second list with dicts in the second list with matching key names having precedence.

```
list1: [
{u'type': u'local-service', u'command': u'something', u'name': 
u'AUTODISCOVER'},
{u'type': u'pager-service', u'command': u'something', 
u'name': u'RPC'},
{u'type': u'local-service', u'command': u'something', u'name': u'PING''} ]

list2: [
{u'type': u'local-service', u'command': u'different', u'name': u'AUTODISCOVER'} ]
```

The resulting list would be:

```
list: [
{u'type': u'local-service', u'command': u'different', u'name': u'AUTODISCOVER'},
{u'type': u'pager-service', u'command': u'something', u'name': u'RPC'},
{u'type': u'local-service', u'command': u'something', u'name': u'PING''} ]
```

In my jinja2 template, I have this:

```
{% set services = item.services | union( server_types[item.type].services ) %}
{% for service in services | sort(attribute='name') %}
{{ service.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Above was for some debugging output
This works properly and lists the services name attribute sorted.

```
{% for service in services | map(attribute='name') | list | unique %}
define  service{
    use                   {{ service.type | default('local-service') }}
    host_name             {{ item.host }}
    service_description   {{ service.name }}
    check_command         {{ service.command }}
}
{% endfor %}
```

This results in this error

```
AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'name'
```

So it seems pretty clear that it is converting the dict object to a string and trying to map it which results in the error. But looking at the docs, my syntax seems correct, and it works as a dict object in the sort() filter in the first loop. So why is the map function failing for me in the second loop?

Comment: `services | map(attribute='name') | list` takes only `name` attribute from every element in `services` list and form a new list.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more testing and you are correct. I believe a custom jinja2 filter is the correct way to do this. If you post this as an answer I will mark it correct as it does answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from comments:

> `services | map(attribute='name') | list` takes only `name` attribute from every element in `services` list and form a new list

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, the map filter returns a list of the value of the key specified by attribute and was *not* the cause of the error. The error is actually from this line:

"service_description   {{ service.name }}"

because the list being looped over is now just a list of strings and not the full dicts. I made it confusing since service.type would have thrown the error except that I specified a default value in case it wasn't defined. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: btw, say some of the items within `services` (list of dicts) do not have `name` attribute... Would there be any way to `default` that specific `name` attribute in this form of syntax?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I did not figure out how to google it before I asked the previous question.. the answer is `services | map(attribute='name', default=['dummy_service'])|list` Hope it may help someone...

Comment: Question raised because of the following ansible error: `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'`. Found the answer here: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/557 (google query: `jinja2 map(attribute)+default attribute value`)